# Why do I have to use "numeral_nat" or "numeral.simps" when proving a simple computable equality of naturals in Isabelle

Tags: isabelle

Take this standard definition for the factorial function:

```
primrec factorial :: "nat ⇒ nat"
  where
    "factorial 0 = 1"
  | "factorial (Suc n) = (Suc n) * (factorial n)"
```

If we ask for `value "factorial 3"`, Isabelle will predictably give us `6`. However, if we try to make that a lemma, it'll fail:

```
lemma "factorial (3::nat) = (6::nat)"
  by simp
(* Failed to apply initial proof method *)
```

`simp`, `auto`, and even `arith` fail to find a solution. However, if we add `numeral_nat` or `numeral.simps`, `simp` can solve it:

```
lemma "factorial (3::nat) = (6::nat)"
  by (simp add: numeral_nat)

lemma "factorial (3::nat) = (6::nat)"
  by (simp add: numeral.simps)
```

Funnily enough, in both of these proofs Isabelle gives the warning "`Ignoring duplicate rewrite rule`", which means that it should already know about these. Furthermore, Isabelle has no problem proving that `"3*2*1 = 6"`, which puzzles me even more about how these lemmas are being used.

So, if this is such a simple and easily computable equality - so much so that Isabelle *can* compute it with the `value` command - and these rules were apparently already present, why can't Isabelle solve the lemma without them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`numeral_nat` contains 7 lemmas:

```
thm numeral_nat
(*
  Numeral1 = Suc 0
  numeral (num.Bit0 ?n) = Suc (numeral (Num.BitM ?n))
  numeral (num.Bit1 ?n) = Suc (numeral (num.Bit0 ?n))
  Num.BitM num.One = num.One
  Num.BitM (num.Bit0 ?n) = num.Bit1 (Num.BitM ?n)
  Num.BitM (num.Bit1 ?n) = num.Bit1 (num.Bit0 ?n)
  1 = Suc 0
*)
```

while `simp` complains about 4 of them:

```
Ignoring duplicate rewrite rule:
Num.BitM num.One ≡ num.One 
Ignoring duplicate rewrite rule:
Num.BitM (num.Bit0 ?n1) ≡ num.Bit1 (Num.BitM ?n1) 
Ignoring duplicate rewrite rule:
Num.BitM (num.Bit1 ?n1) ≡ num.Bit1 (num.Bit0 ?n1) 
Ignoring duplicate rewrite rule:
1 ≡ Suc 0
```

Therefore, there are `7-4=3` new theorems. Tracing (see `simp_trace`) shows that `numeral_nat(2,3)` are the useful lemmas.

The idiomatic way is (`numeral_eq_Suc` is a bad simp rule in general):

```
lemma "factorial (3::nat) = (6::nat)"
  by (simp add: numeral_eq_Suc)
```

You might wonder why the expansion from `3` to `Suc (Suc (Suc 0)))` is actually necessary, because the definition is `factorial (Suc n) = ...`. The answer in Isabelle is: only for `1`. This is sufficient for most recursive functions and avoids a blow-up of the goal. Try

```
lemma "factorial (6::nat) = A" 
  apply (simp add: numeral_nat(2,3))
```

to see a blown-up goal.

Now `value` works very differently. It has three modes:

1. `value` or `value [code]` (`eval` tactic) generated the Standard ML code and executes it. You trust the code equations and the compiler.
2. `value [nbe]` (`normalization` tactic) is normalization by evaluation (also uses codes generation). "The stack of code to be trusted is considerable" (https://isabelle.in.tum.de/dist/Isabelle2021/doc/codegen.pdf)
3. `value [simp]` (`code_simp` tactic) uses the simplifier. Fully trustable.

Even in the last case, the simplifier is called with specific parameters and theorems, not the default ones, like you did. Hence the difference.

Comment: Great answer! One question still remains though: *Why are any of these lemmas needed in the first place?*. If `factorial 3` eventually reduces to `3*2*1` (right?), why can `simp` prove `3*2*1 = 6` without them, but not `factorial 3 = 6`?

Comment: The definition is  `factorial (Suc n) = ...`. So the question becomes: When do you want to transform a numeral into `Suc (Suc ... (0)...)`? The answer in Isabelle is: only for 1. This is sufficient for most recursive functions and avoids a blow-up of the goal. Try `lemma "factorial (6::nat) = A"   apply (simp add: numeral_nat(2,3))` to see a blown-up goal.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense... and deserves to be in the answer! Add that in and I'll gladly accept it (I'd add a suggested edit myself, but unfortunately the edit queue is full)